# Unable to login to account

Tags: macos, user-account, login

I am unable to login to my main account. This is pretty bad because that's the only account on my computer that I know the password to. I'm posting this as root. The user doesn't show up on the login screen or in the switch-user menu. You may think this is a duplicate, but I'm not supposed to delete/make a user. So this doesn't apply. This Mac also has a firmware password that I don't know, so I can't use Recovery Mode. Any help would be immensely appreciated.

I'm using macOS Sierra 10.12.1.

**EDIT**: I should note I can `su` to my account.

Answer (score 1):

For now, you've a couple of options to fix this, but pray you'r Mac's connected to the internet.

1. If you've enabled 'Reset passcode with Apple ID' in System Preferences, great!    But... why this thing *probably* wouldn't work is---

   - You're Mac's disconnected from the internet (in some cases it might work)
   - You haven't set up iCloud on your Mac
   - Dang you forgot the iCloud passcode as well.
2. Take it to an Apple authorised service centre. You *might* be able to recover it if you still have the bill and warranty details of your Mac.
3. I've never heard of firmware passcode. Clearly, you have access to the internet so you could probably look up possible passcode (like I don't know, 000 or passcode123 or something, keep trying as long as it doesn't lock you out).
4. Otherwise, uhhh, there's absolutely nothing you can do. Apple devices are known for their superior encryption technology and safety. Illegal breaking in to your computer is hard, but maybe (*maybe*) possible.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have set up iCloud and reset w/Apple ID, but I can't figure out how to actually do the reset.